# divs and overflows

Tags: html, css

I have following div pattern:

```
<div id="red">
   <div id="green">
       <div id="blue"></div>
       <div id="blue"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

> *red: centralize whole page, position:absolute
>
> *green: sub panel position:absolute
>
> *blue: sub panel position:absolute!

Why does the blue panel overflows then green panel? I dont want to use height in blue panel?

[image]

Comment: we need some more css here, with only the position we can't possibly know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Elements with `position: absolute` are taken out of the layout flow, so they don't affect the position of other elements. So, if you have a container with a div inside, and the inner div has `position: absolute`, its height won't be informed to the parent, and the container will act as empty, unless you explicitly give it height.

A side note: IDs must be unique, you can't have two elements with the same ID as you do with `blue`. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height and overflow:hidden in green, which should hide any children including blue. But, blue has `position:absolute` property allows them to overflow their parent. Need to change to `position:relative` or other position besides absolute if you want to hide within.